# Looking for a simple way to obtain a databse sample

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a feature wich needs to be througthly tested.
To do that I need some production data but the production dataset is way to big to be retrieved on the dev environnement.
So I thought : "I have to write a script that will retrieve the sample data from a datawarehouse and put it in the dev environnement." But it is not as simple as that considering the schema populated by 190 tables and the many relations between them. So creating this *consistent* sample is a real headache.
The way I see things there are no easy way to achieve this but I'm not almighty and I was wondering if any of you ever run into the problem before and found a solution.

By the way the Database system is MySQL 5.5

Thanks for any thoughts brought upon this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy tables by doing:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

CREATE TABLE MyDB.Table1 LIKE ThatDB.Table1;
INSERT INTO MyDB.Table1 SELECT * FROM ThatDB.Table1;  <<-- optional.

CREATE TABLE MyDB.Table2 LIKE ThatDB.Table2;
INSERT INTO MyDB.Table2 SELECT * FROM ThatDB.Table2;  <<-- optional

....

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks but this will be equivalent to dump the production data to the dev env, which is not possible due to technicals limitations

Comment: @Maskime, you can drop the `INSERT INTO ...` and insert your own data instead.